# How to Pivot this Scenario

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have 5 tables:Documents, DocumentTypes, Keywords, DocumentType_Keywords and Document_Keywords.
Keywords schema is:

```
Id | Name
```

DocumentTypes schema is:

```
Id | Name
```

DocumentType_Keywords schema is:

```
Id | DocumentType_Id | Keyword_Id
```

Documents schema is:

```
Id | Name | DocumentType
```

Document_Keywords schema is:

```
Id | Keyword_id | Document_Id | Value
```

In plain English, a document has many keywords, according to it's `Document_Type`.

As you can imagine I have a unknow number of keywords at compile time, but I would like to have a query that outputs:

```
Document Name | Keyword Named 1 | Keyword Named 2 | ... | Keyword Named N  
My Doc 1        Original          Leo               ...   Hey!
My Doc 2        NULL              David             ...   NULL
My Doc 3        NULL              NULL              ...   NULL
My Doc 4        Not Original      Kevin             ...   China
```

Pls note that there is no summarization here

Comment: Although this example has sums, it's still basically the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: @JamesZ actually I found out that the 'max' is a key point in it...

Comment: The dynamic pivot trick JamesZ pointed out will work for your situation. Yes `Pivot` needs an aggregate function like `max` but as long as their either is none or 1 value for specific cell that won't matter.